# j1939 custom module communication

Tags: arduino, can-bus

I am in the middle of building a custom Canbus IO module based off an Atmega2560 chip. The module will have 10 high current outputs with pwm control and current feedback, 20 digital inputs, 5 analog inputs and 4 0-5v analog outputs. I've been working on figuring out the J1939 message structure I'll be using. These modules will be slave devices being controlled by a master ECU. Since more than one of these modules may be on the same network, I've added a CAN Address switch to each module so the user can select the CAN ID 1-255 of each unit. The plan was to have each module broadcast the state of all the digital inputs in a single CAN message. If I Select  0xFF00 as the PGN ID and then use the 8 bytes to represent the state in bit form for the status of the input for that particular module then how does the master know which module the message came from? Is the module address in the CANbus message?

I've been looking at the arduino CANBUS examples and it looks like you can filter based on PGN but I don't see anything to filter based on source address or destination address.

Can someone provide some clarification on how I might do this?

Comment: J1939 encodes the source address as the 8 least-significant bits of the extended CAN identifier. You should be able program your CAN interface to filter that part out, though I'd stick with software filtering unless you've got performance issues. I suspect that you may be better off picking an MCU with a built-in CAN peripheral in place of the ATmega2560 though.

Comment: So I can send a message by adding the priority,PGN and then source?
for example if I send 0x0CFF00FE this means:
priority 3
PGN 65280
source address 254

is this correct?

Comment: @jonfarrugia You are correct. Take note that all proprietary PGNs (65280-65535) are broadcast messages, meaning that their destination address is always 255.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as doynax mentioned, the 8 least significant bits are always reserved for the source address of a node. If you will be placing this network on a vehicle's CAN bus, it is important to note that if you do not claim a source address on the vehicle bus, you may get a NAK from the main ECU whenever you try to place foreign information on the bus.

In order to prevent this issue, you may have to do an claim address procedure for each custom node on your network. This is where you send out PGN 60928 as a broadcast (destination address 0xFF) and every node on the network should respond on that PGN with their own source address (assuming all nodes comply to this specification, not all do). If a common source address is seen on the replies, then you know that it is not available.

See the following slideshow for more information starting on page 39
[J1939](http://www.simmasoftware.com/j1939-presentation.pdf)